# Kickboxing workout structure

Tags: home-exercise, martial-arts

What is a good way to structure home kickboxing workouts? I have a punching bag and protective gear and am technically and physically capable of doing most punches and kicks.

I am going to start kickboxing classes in a few weeks, but these are only once a week, so I want to keep fit between them and I also want to be a bit prepared. In addition to kickboxing, I do strength training three times a week.

Specifically, how long is a good training session, how should I warm up, how much of training should be technical training (and what should be trained), how much should be more "cardio" focused?